# How to sum specific rows and columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
pnr mnd pris 
  1   1  600
  1   7  900
  2   1  600
  2   7  600
  3   1   40
  3   7   40
```

I have trouble how to sum specific rows on the columns. Looking at the above, the table is called travel and it has 3 columns:

- pnr - Personal Number
- mnd - Month
- Pris - Price

So what I want is to sum total of the price for the a specific month, so in this case, it should be 1240 USD and month 1. For the month 7, it should be 1540 USD.

I have trouble to do the query correct. So far from I have tried is this:

```
SELECT t.rnr, t.mnd, SUM(t.pris)
FROM travel AS t
WHERE t.mnd = 1
```

The result I get is 3720 USD which I have no idea how the SQL managed to calculate this for me.

Appreciate if someone could please help me out!

Comment: Skip the `WHERE` clause and add `GROUP BY pnr, mnd` at the end to get sum per product and month, keep the WHERE if you only want to see one month at a time

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to drop the `pnr` column from the output (it is not relevant and will cause your data to split) and add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t.mnd, SUM(t.pris)
FROM travel AS t
WHERE t.mnd = 1
GROUP BY t.mnd
```

Live demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b34ec2bb9c077c2d74ffc66748c5c142

(The use of an aggregate function without grouping, as you've got now, is not a standard SQL feature and can often be turned off in MySQL. If turned on, you might not always get the result you expected/intended.)

Answer (score 0):

just group your result with `mnd` column

```
SELECT t.mnd, SUM(t.pris)
FROM travel AS t
group by t.mnd
```